# Is it acceptable for a select option in a form to be 'selected' and 'disabled'?

Tags: html, forms

Is it acceptable for a select field to be both `selected` and `disabled`?

For example:

```
<select required name="select_name" class="select_class">
<option selected disabled value="select">select</option>
<!-- other options here -->
</select>
```

It is the first option in the select field and I need it to be:

- the default value that is displayed on the front end
- unabled to be selected
- and make it so that an alternative option must be selected (as the select field itself is `required`)

**Edit:**  It seems to be 'working' on the front end in FF 30, Chrome 35 and IE 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a common technique. If there are downsides to it, I don't know them yet, but I'm sure the community with bring them up.

To make it usable for the required attribute the defaultSelected and disabled option should have the explicit value "":

```
<select required name="select_name" class="select_class">
    <option selected disabled value="">select</option>
    <!-- other options here -->
</select>
```

Comment: It's not only absolutley fine. The definition of placeholder option in HTML5 was changed about 1 or 2 years ago to honour the semantic use pattern/technique.